# Can't start MySQL Server with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, port

2021-04-27 21:04:35 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10049: The requested address is invalid in this context.

2021-04-27 21:04:35 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-04-27 21:04:35 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Answer (score -1):

I think you already have another service running on port 3306 and that is why MySQl cannot use it, so two solutions:

1. Change MySQL port editing mysql.ini (Usually located where MySQL is installed, like C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini) and change the line port=3306 to use another port number
2. Identify what service is using that port and kill it:

- Use nestat to identify the process is using the port 3306

```sh
netstat -aon | findstr 3306
```

- The last column of the result is the process id (PID), use it to identify what application is blocking the port and with that information you can kill/uninstall the app is blocking MySQL.

```sh
 tasklist | findstr <PID>
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: There are no programms/PIDS listef if  I type in netstat -aon | findstr 3306.